# Is there any way to detect the height of the android actionBar before actually showing it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to set a custom background image in the android action bar for ICS. I rescale it programmatically before showing it, in order to fit exactly in the actionBar. The problem is that I need to know in advance the height of the actionBar but calling actionBar.getHeight() before it is actually shown, returns 0.

If I just try to include it as the actionBar's background in an xml style, there is no way to rescale it by keeping the aspect ratio.
If I try to set the background after the actionBar is shown, I get some weird results with the image floating on top, cut in half.

It seems the only way is to resize it programmaticaly. Is there any way to detect the size of the actionBar before I actually request to show it?

Thank you

Comment: I got the same question and tried to solve the same way as yours (i.e. tried to resize the background and maintain the aspect ratio). I solved it by using a nine-patch image background.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use draw9patch image?
DEfault size of the ActionBar is 48dip

So other values you might want to know

```
 <!-- Default height of an action bar. -->
<dimen name="action_bar_default_height">48dip</dimen>
<!-- Vertical padding around action bar icons. -->
<dimen name="action_bar_icon_vertical_padding">8dip</dimen>
<!-- Text size for action bar titles -->
<dimen name="action_bar_title_text_size">18dp</dimen>
<!-- Text size for action bar subtitles -->
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_text_size">14dp</dimen>
<!-- Top margin for action bar subtitles -->
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_top_margin">-3dp</dimen>
<!-- Bottom margin for action bar subtitles -->
<dimen name="action_bar_subtitle_bottom_margin">5dip</dimen>
```

Comment: I suspect these values are likely to change in future.  I think the OP wants to get the height programmatically.

Comment: ActionBar size is dependent on your environment. (eg. values 48dp, values-land 40dp, values-sw600dp 56dp)

Comment: The nine patch image solves the underlying issue (i.e. resize the background and maintain its aspect ratio).

Answer (score 3):

```
int height = 0;
TypedValue typeValue = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, typeValue, true);
height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typeValue.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

[Source](http://www.exsoul-browser.com/2012/11/30/how-to-get-action-bar-height/)

Comment: This works but does not answer the underlying question of resizing the background and maintain its aspect ratio.

Comment: is there any way to reduce the specified height to hide the action bar?

Comment: `getActionBar().hide();`